# using variable value in custom aplication tag

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to use value of parameters of a stored procedure but I cannot use select, as I am already using select to set the value of the application customized tag like in below stored procedure:

```
USE [Kustom]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--EXEC LaminasListAdd 22, 22.00, 0.00

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LaminasListAdd] 
    (@Lamina INTEGER, 
     @Value float, 
     @Total float)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT _LIST_ = 'Laminas', _LIST_INSERT_ = @Lamina, @Value, @Value, 2, @Lamina

    SELECT @Total = @Total + @Value

    SELECT Lamina = ''
    SELECT Value = ''
    SELECT Total = @Total

    SELECT _SET_AND_NOTIFY_ = 'FaceAmount', @Total
 END
```

Can you tell me how to get the value of parameters in

```
_LIST_INSERT_ = @Lamina, @Value, @Value, 2, @Lamina
```

please?

The customized keyword of application with *** are to be set with key value pairs

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: apologies for not tagging RDBMS, I am using sql-server